# What is the reason for the bar notation used on $g_1 , g_2, g_3$... in Allen Hatcher's book?

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation

I have some confusion about the notation used in Allen Hatcher book.

It is written that we consider  the  loop  $(f.\bar{ g_1}) .(g_1.f_2.\bar{g_2} ).(g_2.f_3.\bar{g_3})....(g_{m-1}.f_m) $
[image]

My confusion : why does he use the bar notation on $g_1 , g_2, g_3$...

My thinking : could we directly write this without using the bar notation  $(f.{ g_1}) .(g_1.f_2.{g_2} ).(g_2.f_3.{g_3})....(g_{m-1}.f_m) $ I think that $\bar{g_1}$ may refer to the conjugate of $g_1$.

Comment: I guess it rather means that you take the reverse loop.

Comment: okay @TheSilverDoe

Comment: Typo: $f_1 \cdot  \bar g_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On p. 26 Hatcher writes

> Given two paths $f ,g : I→X$ such that $f (1) = g(0)$, there is a composition or product path $f \cdot g$ that traverses first $f$ and then $g$.

On p. 27 he defines $\bar f$ for a path $f$ from $x_0$ to $x_1$. This is the inverse path from $x_1$ back to $x_0$.^

In the expressions $f \cdot \bar{ g_1}$, $g_1\cdot f_2 \cdot \bar{g_2}$ etc. it is essential that the bar paths are used; omitting the bars produces **undefined** expressions.